# When solving inequalities that involve logarithms, exponentials and the quadratic formula, which way does the sign turn?

Tags: calculus, inequality

I always get confused when solving inequalities that involve logarithms, exponentials and quadratics that require the quadratic formula because I don't know where the sign is supposed to turn.

See the examples below:

**On logarithms and exponents**
$$1 \ge \log_2(x) \Leftrightarrow 2 \text{ ?? } x$$

Or the other way around:

$$1 \ge \log_2(x) \Leftrightarrow x \text{ ?? } 2$$

or

$$2^x \le 256 \Leftrightarrow x \text{ ?? } 8$$

**On the quadratic formula**

$$0 \ge x^2+3x+2 \Leftrightarrow x \text{ ?? }\frac{-3\pm \sqrt{3^2+4(1\cdot2)}}{2(1)}$$

Basically I have two questions:

1. How do I know which way the sign turns in the above situations?
2. What happens exactly between $2^x = 256$ and $x = \log_2(8)$? Are any operations omitted or is the exponent "swapped" with a logarithm because that's the logical thing to do?

Answer (score 3):

Let $a\geq b$. Then if $f$ is an **increasing function**, then applying the function on the inequality retains its direction, i.e.
$$f(a)\geq f(b). $$
On the other hand, if $g$ is a **decreasing function**, then applying the function reverses the inequality, i.e.
$$g(a)\leq g(b).$$

---

Consider the function defined by $f(x) = 2^x$ which is an increasing function. Hence
$$1 \geq \log_2 (x) \implies f(1) \geq f(\log_2(x)) \implies 2\geq x.$$

For the quadratic it's slightly more complicated as more steps are used. Consider the quadratic function
$$q(x) = ax^2+bx+c,\quad a\neq 0. $$

Then let $x_1, x_2$ (let $x_1$ be the smaller of the two) be roots of $q(x) = 0$. The real line is divided into $3$ intervals, namely
$$I_1 = (-\infty,x_1],\quad I_2 = [x_1,x_2],\quad I_3 = [x_2,\infty).$$
Consider the inequality
$$0 \leq q(x).$$
If $a>0$, then the inequality is solved for $x\in I_1 \cup I_3$, i.e. if $x\leq x_1$ or $x \geq x_2$.

If $a < 0$, then the inequality is solved for $x\in I_2$, i.e. if $x_1\leq x \leq x_2$.

For the inequality in the other direction, namely
$$0\geq q(x)$$
the two solutions above are interchanged.

Answer (score 2):

One way I remember it is that for bases $b > 1$ applying exponents or logarithms is strictly increasing, so the inequality doesn't change directions. So, if I know $u < v$ then I also know $b^u < b^v$ if exponentiation is appropriate, and $\log_b(u) < \log_b(v)$ if taking logarithms is appropriate.

For instance, say you know $1 \geqslant \log_2(x)$. To get rid of the logarithm, you should exponentiate using the base $b=2$, right? It follows that $2 = 2^1 \geqslant 2^{\log_2(x)} = x$. Notice that the inequality did not change directions.

Similarly, suppose you know $2^x \leqslant 256$. In this case, you would apply $\log_2$ to both sides, and find $x = \log_2(2^x) \leqslant \log_2(256) = 8$. Again, the inequality did not change directions.

Be wary, though - if your base $b <1$ then applying exponents or logorithms is strictly DECREASING, and the inequality DOES change directions. For instance, $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^x \leqslant 1/256$ implies $x = \log_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^x\right) \geqslant \log_{\frac{1}{2}}(1/256) = 8$

As for use of the quadratic formula, it mostly depends on the sign of the leading coefficient - picture upward facing and downward facing parabolas.